# Did I write/use concat correctly for a password generator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

We have to generate a random password between 8-128 characters. The user is supposed to get a series of ok/cancel options for the characters they'd like to include (uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and special characters). Then the password should generate. I'm not sure if I used the concat correctly. Although the confirm windows pop-up, the button doesn't generate anything. Not sure if I just mislabeled something, or I am totally off.

```
//Lowercase
 var lowerCase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

 //Uppercase
 var upperCase = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ];

 //Numeric
 var numValue = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

 //Special Characters
 var spChar = ['@', '%', '+', '\\', '/', "'", '!', '#', '$', '^', '?', ':', ',', ')', '(', '}', '{', ']', '[', '~', '-', '_', '.'];

 //var choices outside the if statement to concat Not sure if I should put this inside a function

 var choices;

 // Length of password, this is where the user selects how long their password should be(8 - 128 characters)

 function generatePassword() {

     var number = 0
     while (number < 8 || number > 128) {
         number = window.prompt("How long would you like your password to be? Enter a number between 8-128");
         console.log(number);
     }

     //Where while loop ends
     console.log("after ", number)

     //Prompt for character types
     var lcChoice = confirm("Would you like your password to contain lowercase characters?");
     var ucChoice = confirm("How about uppercase characters?");
     var numchoice = confirm("Would you like numbers?");
     var spChoice = confirm("How about special characters? Like & or $?");

     //If for  negative on all 4 options - this doesn't return anything

     if (!lcChoice && !ucChoice && !numchoice && spChoice) {
         prompt = alert("You must choose a criteria!");
     }

     //Else if for all 4 character options
     if (lcChoice && ucChoice && numchoice && spChoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(numValue, upperCase, lowerCase);
     }

     //Else if for 3 options (lc, uc, n) (uc, n, sp) (n, sp, lc) (sp, lc, uc)
     else if (lcChoice && ucChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = lcCase.concat(numValue, upperCase);
     } else if (lcChoice && ucChoice && spChoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(spChar, upperCase);
     } else if (lcChoice && spChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(numValue, spChar);
     } else if (spChoice && ucChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(numValue, upperCase);
     }

     //Else if for 2 options (sp,n) (sp,lc) (sp, uc) (lc, n) (lc, uc) (n, uc)
     else if (spChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(numValue);
     } else if (spChoice && lcChoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(lowerCase);
     } else if (spChoice && ucChoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(upperCase);
     } else if (lcChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(numValue);
     } else if (lcChoice && ucChoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(upperCase);
     } else if (numchoice && ucChoice) {
         choices = numValue.concat(upperCase);
     }

     //else if for one choice
     else if (lcChoice) {
         choices = lowerCase;
     } else if (ucChoice) {
         choices = upperCase;
     } else if (numchoice) {
         choices = numValue;
     } else if (spChoice) {
         choice = spChar;
     }

     var pwd = [];
     for (i = 0; i === number; i++) {
         pwd += choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
     }

     
     return pwd;
 }

 //Get references to the #generate element
 var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

 //Write password to the #password input
 function writePassword() {
     var password = generatePassword();
     var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

     passwordText.value = password;
 }

 //Add event listener to generate button - This code was given to us
 generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

Comment: Hard to tell if you actually have errors in your code or if you somehow think it was going to be bold text in the middle of code blocks. Please fix your code....

Comment: `choices = alert("You must choose a criteria!");` <-- why are you setting alert to a variable?

Comment: you can change your code to 4 if statements, there is no reason to do every combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are not getting anything from your password generator is here:

```
for (i = 0; i === number; i++) {
        pwd += choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.number)]
    }
```

choices.number is undefined (this is referring to the number property of the choices object, which doesnt exist)

Please try changing this to choices.length (the length of the array)

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code which includes, `choices = spChoice.concat(numValue, upperCase, lowerCase);` where it should be `spChar` and similarly `choices = lcChoice.concat(numValue, upperCase);`. Then here `pwd += choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.number)]` there's no `choices.number` as it's a string. it should be `choices.length` instead.

```js
//Lowercase
 var lowerCase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

 //Uppercase
 var upperCase = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", ];

 //Numeric
 var numValue = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

 //Special Characters
 var spChar = ['@', '%', '+', '\\', '/', "'", '!', '#', '$', '^', '?', ':', ',', ')', '(', '}', '{', ']', '[', '~', '-', '_', '.'];

 //var choices outside the if statement to concat Not sure if I should put this inside a function

 var choices;

 // Length of password, this is where the user selects how long their password should be(8 - 128 characters)

 function generatePassword() {

     var number = 0
     while (number < 8 || number > 128) {
         number = window.prompt("How long would you like your password to be? Enter a number between 8-128");
         console.log(number);
     }

     //Where while loop ends
     console.log("after ", number)

     //Prompt for character types
     var lcChoice = confirm("Would you like your password to contain lowercase characters?");
     var ucChoice = confirm("How about uppercase characters?");
     var numchoice = confirm("Would you like numbers?");
     var spChoice = confirm("How about special characters? Like & or $?");

     //If for  negative on all 4 options - this doesn't return anything

     if (!lcChoice && !ucChoice && !numchoice && !spChoice) {
         prompt = alert("You must choose a criteria!");
     }

     //Else if for all 4 character options
     if (lcChoice && ucChoice && numchoice && spChoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(numValue, upperCase, lowerCase);
     }

     //Else if for 3 options (lc, uc, n) (uc, n, sp) (n, sp, lc) (sp, lc, uc)
     else if (lcChoice && ucChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(numValue, upperCase);
     } else if (lcChoice && ucChoice && spChoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(spChar, upperCase);
     } else if (lcChoice && spChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(numValue, spChar);
     } else if (spChoice && ucChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(numValue, upperCase);
     }

     //Else if for 2 options (sp,n) (sp,lc) (sp, uc) (lc, n) (lc, uc) (n, uc)
     else if (spChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(numValue);
     } else if (spChoice && lcChoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(lowerCase);
     } else if (spChoice && ucChoice) {
         choices = spChar.concat(upperCase);
     } else if (lcChoice && numchoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(numValue);
     } else if (lcChoice && ucChoice) {
         choices = lowerCase.concat(upperCase);
     } else if (numchoice && ucChoice) {
         choices = numValue.concat(upperCase);
     }

     //else if for one choice
     else if (lcChoice) {
         choices = lowerCase;
     } else if (ucChoice) {
         choices = upperCase;
     } else if (numchoice) {
         choices = numValue;
     } else if (spChoice) {
         choice = spChar;
     }

     var pwd = [];
     for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
         pwd += choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)]
     }

     return pwd;
 }

 //Get references to the #generate element
 var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

 //Write password to the #password input
 function writePassword() {
     var password = generatePassword();
     var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
      console.log(password)
     passwordText.value = password;
 }

 //Add event listener to generate button - This code was given to us
 generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="password">
<button id="generate">Generate</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that! After checking it all once again, it still doesn't generate a code? Is my last for loop incorrect?

Comment: You can actually run my code here on SO and see. I have already fixed the problems for you which I have mentioned on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After editing the labels, I needed to change the length or iteration of the function to be i < numbers.